# Vue prop validation is not called

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I create a component with input properties:

```
export default {
    data() {
       :
       :
    },     
    props: {
        rowsContent: {
            type: Object,
            default: null,
            validator: function(value) {
                console.log("In validator");
            }

        },
        rowsPerPage: {
            type: Number,
            default: 10,
        },
    }
```

I tried to pass different type of parameters, and got no error message.
Moreover, no *"In validator"* message is printed to console.

Any idea?

Comment: Try adding a `return true` after the console log. Furthermore your `data` part looks messed up. You should see an error in the console.

Comment: Can you show the code where you try to use the properties.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the reason, but it is working if I use component tag like `<tag></tag>`. If I use like `<tag/>`, it does not work. See example here. https://codesandbox.io/s/z6rlzl998p

**EDIT:** *Vue does not support self-closing tags as components*: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8664 (as mentioned in comment)

Comment: Vue [does not support self-closing tags](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8664) as components  (because  with a few historical exceptions [self-closing html tags are not valid HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/3412322).)